# How to deploy to heroku using a browserify-generated file, but without checking in the generated file to git?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, browserify

I have a node.js app, and I'm using browserify to compile my client js. I run something like `browserify public/index.js -o public/bundle/bundle.js` to generate the public/bundle/index.js file, which is included in the app.

Since it's generated, I don't want to check the bundle to git. I have the script that runs browserify in the "postinstall" part of my package.json.

But when I try to deploy, since I have not checked in the bundle file, I get a "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory".

Is it possible to deploy without adding the bundle to git?